# Is there any secure storage in Android through Monodroid out of the box?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Like many people - I am developing an app with a shared codebase (Windows Store + Android + MonoTouch  + [later] WP8).

Also, as with many apps, I have local state that I need to persist for this app.

One piece of information I store is an authentication token for the signed-in user.  On the Windows Store platform I have implemented the storage of this with a mixture of roaming settings (`ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings`) for the token's ancillary data (user name and issued date) and the `PasswordVault` for the actual token value.  Thus the token is protected from OS-level introspection, because it is encrypted by the OS.

Now I'm implementing the same interface for my MonoDroid build, and I can't see any way, provided by the platform, to store data that can only be decrypted by my application - in the same way as the password vault can be used for Store apps.

As a result, at the moment, I'm simply using the `Android.Content.ISharedPreferences` interface via the `Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences` method to read and write these values.

So am I correct in my assumption that the platform (MonoDroid or Android) offers no secure storage OOB?  Is the only alternative to implement encryption within the app - which will of course require baking the encryption key into the code?  Or can I grab the certificate used to sign the app and use that as a key?

Ultimately it's not the end of the world if I can't encrypt this data, since the token *is* time-limited anyway - but it would be nice if I could actually do it *properly*!

Answer (score 1):

You could use it with a combination of [Keychain API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) (available in API level 14 onwards) and encrypting the data with [Cipher API](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) using the certificate from the Keychain api.

Take note:
According to Android Security Overview document, there is no guarantees if the device is rooted: 
http://source.android.com/tech/security/index.html#rooting-of-devices

Comment: yeah the rooting of devices is potentially a headache from a security point of view; as is the installation of custom roms (it's relatively simple to build a custom rom that snoops on user data).  However, the user does that thing at their own risk (I certainly have!)

This is interesting, I'll have to see if there are any device-specific certificates that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this quoting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918262/bluetooth-out-of-band-oob-pairing-on-android/7102652#7102652) can help you:

> On the android side OOB is not supported in the public API so things
>   get tricky. I believe this is because Honeycomb 3.2 does not have a
>   bluez stack that officially supports OOB bonding, but Google has some
>   kind of implementation coded in. I believe this because if you look at
>   gingerbread source code for the Bluetooth Adapter and Bluetooth Device
>   classes you can see OOB methods available but not exposed through the
>   documented API.
>
> These methods are still public so you can call them through
>   reflection. Using reflection you can also get all of the method
>   signatures in a class. This is how I figured out what methods I had
>   available to me.
>
> Beware though that many are not documented and it's not obvious what
>   some do. The important ones to make note of are the
>   readOutOfBandData() in the adapter class and setDeviceOutOfandData()
>   in the device class.

Comment: Oh oops! By 'OOB' I mean 'out of the box'! I.e is there a platform provided mechanism for encrypted storage provided out of the box :-). Gonna change the question title...

Comment: ;o) It's ok, I misunderstood.